# GridView, RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

Firing a RowDataBound event, my question is how do I pull out the DataKey for GridviewRowEventArgs e?

I have a table of Publications and surprisingly enough the key is PublicationID, however I do not have a boundfield to publication id but have it specified as a datakeyname.  I can get the information using:

```
int pID =Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,"PublicationID"));
```

But was wondering if there is a more elegant way of getting the information?!

Also, if I investigate e, i can see the underlying table (publication) which also has a child table owner, does anybody know how I could, from the point in the app i.e. inside the RowDataBound event pull information out of the child table?

This is all .Net 3.0, C#.

Thanks, R.

Comment: if the way you're doing it works, what's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

((GridView)sender).DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty interesting.  I have a second question, is there a way of retrieving the underlying datasource in a similar way?

My GridView has an underlying dataset with two relationships in it, I was wondering if I can pick up one of those relationship and read through it to get at some data, rather than query the database or a global dataset again?  It seems logically possible.

I tried:  DataSet x = (DataSet)((GridView)sender).DataSource; but got Null.

Comment: I tried your tutorial on  check boxes but kept getting an error on: <%# Bind("Include") %>, added column to my table, set the default value to 0, but this Bind component threw an error, something about converting from a number, bit weird.

Comment: To the first comment: You get the key info you need from e.Row.DataItem and use that to retrieve data from the DataSet - but the DataSet needs to be in scope.  So you might have to retrieve the DataSet, set a private variable of the page to that DataSet and then bind your GridView.  And then within the RowDataBound event the DataSet would be visible.

Comment: For the check boxes did you have:
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Include") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>

and if you defined the Include column in sql you couldn't have:
select 0 as Include....
you have to have
select cast(0 as bit) as Include